# Как сгенерировать state для OneDriveApi | CURL | PHP | REST API

Tags: php, curl, onedrive

Как мне сгенерировать state для имитации oauth2? Есть такой запрос:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/1111111/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?state=9604adbb6b555a9a3d222b453e9cf9a5&scope=123123
```

Обычно, я использую **League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider** для этих целей, но мне надоел редирект, который создает кучу проблем, поэтому я решил перейти на curl.

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://login.microsoftonline.com/db1e2.../oauth2/v2.0/authorize");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        "state=9604adbb6b555a9a3d222b453e9cf9a5&scope=123123...");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);

    dd($server_output);

    curl_close ($ch);
```

Тут ничего сложного, просто запрос POST с получение ответа. Но из-за того, что я не знаю, что вставлять в state, у меня ничего не работает!

P.s: то значение, что имеется сейчас я получил из League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider, когда проводил отладку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот и весь ответ.

```
bin2hex(random_bytes(32 / 2))
```